# can not use SSO with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have problems sing in throught Facebook even if I used the official sample application. Than I have deinstaled the updates from official facebook app, and the sample application has started working, but my custom app is still unable to sing in. I get always: this 2 states `Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:45xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx44}`   then it shows loading and facebook action bar, but does not even ask for authentication as it does for sample application and throws this `{Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:45xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx44}`

I have generated different hash with keytoll and different one with in code using hint from an answer, before. I have added the both Hash, to application dashboard. I have added my package correct, and Main Activity too. I can not find what I am missing. please help

Comment: com.facebook.FacebookException: Invalid access token.    this is the exception

Comment: the answer is to disable sandbox mode I have missed it and at official FB tutorial( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ ) it is not mentioned....